# Can we have multiple repositories under a project in gitswarm?

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab, perforce, gitswarm

I bitbucket I can see a project which holds more than one repository.
Is it the same way in Gitswarm?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is not well-suited to the site, because you're asking for general help related to using a software product, rather than help with a specific programming issue or problem. You might have better luck on the GitSwarm help pages, or possibly on SuperUser.

Comment: Helix TeamHub may meet your requirements, as it allows managing multiple repos within a project. More information here: https://www.perforce.com/tutorial-videos/course/getting-started-helix-teamhub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have more than one repo under a GitSwarm project.

You can however put each repo under its own project, then put all these projects under one group.